# Views, add fields, limited options

Tags: drupal-7, view

I have recently developed an odd behaviour in my views. I am trying to generate a simple view that simply lists all entered data of that content type in a table. I have stripped all bells and whistles from the view to get it working but it just won't.

When I create a new view, I can add the relevant fields for the content type, filters etc. It all works as expected. If I then save and try to create another page view for the next content type, all my fields disappear (including the original fields used in the original view). The only fields available are core fields like content:type, content:title, content:post date etc.

I have checked permissions, display values in the content type, searched extensively online. Most people's issue is the relationship hasn't been established but my view doesn't rely on a relationship, it is a simple display view.

Any help or pointers would be truly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance Nelle

Drupal 7.22
Views 7.x-3.7

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Views. See this [bug report](https://drupal.org/node/1954348) for a work-around (disable Views caching and UI Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to remove filters from new page?

There is an **important option** when you use the same view to create many pages or blocks :

when you edit a field or filter, you should choose where to apply modifications (For All displays or this page (override)

Comment: Thanks ProjectAO. That's not the issue. I have the correct override in place. I can't see any of the fields for any content type only core fields as I listed in the original post.